# date variable ASTDT in YYYY-MM-DD format want to convert this into DDMMMYYYY format

Tags: r, date, sas

I have a data frame x with date variable ASTDT in YYYY-MM-DD format. i want to convert this into DDMMMYYYY format. please help me how to select the ASTDT from the data frame and change the format? please note that the ASTDT currently is in DATE format not in character or numeric .

```
x<-as.Date (x$astdt, format="%d%m%Y")
```

used the above peace of code but it is not working.

when used str(x) got the below attribute information which shows ASTDT as Date format.

```
 $ ASTDT      : Date, format: "2003-05-01" "2003-05-13" "2003-08-19" "2004-01-06" ...
```

Comment: Column names are in capital letters, right? astdt vs ASTDT?

Comment: yes was using ASTDT .

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `format()` function here:

```r
dates <- as.Date(c("2003-05-01", "2003-05-13", "2003-08-19", "2004-01-06"))
output <- format(dates, "%d%b%Y")
output

[1] "01May2003" "13May2003" "19Aug2003" "06Jan2004"
```

Comment: OP wants MMM format

Comment: @zx8754 It wasn't clear to me if `MMM` were just a typo for `MM`.  Assuming not, I have updated my answer with what I think _you_ want to see here.

Comment: Thanks Tim Biegeleisen this is also working fine.